# Database error while authenticating user from MongoDB connected with Django app deployed in GCP

Tags: django, mongodb, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed a Django app in Google Cloud Platform. I am using MongoDB atlas to store user's data. I can successfully register and login by running it on localhost. But when I try to register/login directly from the application's URL, it's giving database error. In settings.py file, I have given the connection string of the MongoDB database. How would I be able to access data stored in MongoDB through the application deployed in GCP?

The resources which are used are App Engine along with Cloud SDK to deploy.

The Database connection in settings.py file is as follow:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        
        
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'CLIENT': {
            'name' : 'Example',
           'host':'mongodb+srv://username:password@[host]?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
            'username': 'username',
            'password': 'password',
            'authMechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-1',
        },
    }
}
```

The error is the  following:

```
DatabaseError at /login
No exception message supplied
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://[PROJECT-ID].ew.r.appspot.com/login
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: DatabaseError
Exception Location: /env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py in execute, line 59
Python Executable:  /env/bin/python3.7
Python Version: 3.7.9
Python Path:    
['/srv',
 '/env/bin',
 '/opt/python3.7/lib/python37.zip',
 '/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 17 Nov 2020 12:48:36 +0000

The above exception ( Keyword: None Sub SQL: None FAILED SQL: ('INSERT INTO "django_session" ("session_key", "session_data", "expire_date") VALUES (%(0)s, %(1)s, %(2)s)',) Params: (('[REDACTED_SESSION_KEY]', '[REDACTED_SESSION_DATA]', datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 12, 48, 35, 677384)),) Version: 1.3.3) was the direct cause of the following exception:
/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
ignored_wrapper_args    
(False,
 {'connection': <djongo.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x3e8871fc0790>,
  'cursor': <django.db.backends.utils.CursorDebugWrapper object at 0x3e8871afa790>})
params  
('[REDACTED_SESSION_KEY]',
 '[REDACTED_SESSION_DATA]',
 datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 12, 48, 35, 677384))
self    
<django.db.backends.utils.CursorDebugWrapper object at 0x3e8871afa790>
sql 
('INSERT INTO "django_session" ("session_key", "session_data", "expire_date") '
 'VALUES (%s, %s, %s)')

Variable    Value
db_exe  
DatabaseError()
params  
('[REDACTED_SESSION_KEY]',
 '[REDACTED_SESSION_DATA]',
 datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 12, 48, 35, 677384))
self    
<djongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x3e8871afad90>
sql 
('INSERT INTO "django_session" ("session_key", "session_data", "expire_date") '
 'VALUES (%s, %s, %s)')
```

Comment: Remember never to post sensible data such as keys, passwords, tokens,etc. As well as personal identifiable information (unless you strictly want to and it's a required information) as it can pose a security risk for your application. This [community tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-mongodb-on-appengine) sheds light that such connection is at least possible using NodeJS and App Engine Flexible, and I will therefore believe that it could be possible with Djando on App Engine Flexible. Did you follow some post or could you provide an example app to attempt a repro?

Comment: Thanks Daniel.i will take care of it next time.
I have followed google cloud docs for deploying in app engine standard environment.But both app engine flexible and app engine standard used sql database where as they didn't give information about mongodb.